# was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in C++ and working on a project with QT. I created a header file called imageconvert.h which is as follow:

```
class ImageConvert
{

private:
IplImage *imgHeader;
uchar* newdata;

public:

ImageConvert();
~ImageConvert();
IplImage* QImage2IplImage(QImage *qimg);
QImage* IplImage2QImage(IplImage *iplImg);
};
```

also I defined those public methods in imageconvert.cpp file.

Now, I want to call QImage2IplImage and IplImage2QImage from other cpp file. So i include imageconvert.h in that CPP file and called those two functions.

it gives the the following errors:

```
error: 'QImage2IplImage' was not declared in this scope
error: 'IplImage2QImage' was not declared in this scope
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you call them? How did you create an object from ImageConvert class?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I called them using:                                        
    IplImage* img;
    QImage* img_temp;
    img = QImage2IplImage(image);
    img_temp = IplImage2QImage(img);

Comment: They are member functions of the class `ImageConvert`.  You must declare an object of that type to invoke them.  Otherwise, just make them free functions.

Comment: hi Jonsca, thanks for reply. will you please explain a bit with sample code (I am new in CPP). that would really help me

Comment: See Mat's answer.  I don't mean this in a harsh way at all, but you may want to read up on some of the fundamentals before delving into a comprehensive library like Qt.  I think it will save you a lot of time in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions you've defined are member functions of the `ImageConvert` class. You need an instance of that class to be able to call them.

Something like:

```
ImageConvert ic;
ic.QImage2IplImage(your_QImage_object);
```

If you don't need state to do the conversion, you should make those helper functions `static`. Then you can call them with:

```
ImageConvert::QImage2IplImage(your_QImage_object);
```

without first creating an instance of `ImageConvert`. But please note that you will not be able to use `imgHeader` or `newData` in those static functions - they are member variables, only usable within an instance of that class.

You could also remove these functions from your class and put them in a [`namespace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Comment: Why make them static? Why not use namespaces instead?

Answer (score 3):

### Your question...

How exactly do you call those functions? Given your ImageConverter class, this is how you should be doing it:

```
// First create a new converter
ImageConverter conv;

IplImage* ipl = conv.QImage2IplImage(qimg);
qimg = conv.IplImage2QImage(ipl);
```

### ... And some advice on using classes

Do you by any chance come from a Java or C# background? If so, you should know that in C++ you can also have free functions (that don't belong to any class). You should only use classes when you need to abstract a certain (real world) concept, and not simply as a way to group functions:

```
// image_converter.h
IplImage* QImage2IplImage(const QImage* qimg);
QImage* IplImage2QImage(const IplImage* iplImg);

// someother.cpp
IplImage* ipl = QImage2IplImage(qimg);
qimg = IplImage2QImage(ipl);
```

Notice I added `const` to the function parameters — it's a good thing to be [const correct](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html). Additionaly, you can group your functions in a namespace:

```
// image_converter.h
namespace converter
{
    IplImage* QImage2IplImage(const QImage* qimg);
    QImage* IplImage2QImage(const IplImage* iplImg);
}

// someother.cpp
IplImage* ipl = converter::QImage2IplImage(qimg);
qimg = converter::IplImage2QImage(ipl);
```